# JanRain PHP OpenID: How to check if a provider supports AX programmatically?

Tags: php, openid, janrain, sreg, attribute-exchange

Ok, my problem is that some providers support SREG and some support only AX I need to know how it is that I can request from the provider which methods they support.. I tried looking through the documentation here http://openidenabled.com/files/php-openid/docs/2.1.3/ but I didn't see anything.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422433/openid-simple-registration-sreg-vs-attribute-exchange-ax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faced similar problem.

The below code should help you.

So if

```
function getReturnTo() {
    return sprintf("%s://%s:%s%s/finish_auth.php",
                   getScheme(), $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],
                   $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'],
                   dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
}

function &getConsumer() {
    /**
     * Create a consumer object using the store object created
     * earlier.
     */
    $store = getStore();
    $consumer =& new Auth_OpenID_Consumer($store);
    return $consumer;
}

$consumer = getConsumer();

$return_to = getReturnTo();
$response = $consumer->complete($return_to);

$sreg_resp = Auth_OpenID_SRegResponse::fromSuccessResponse($response);

$ax = new Auth_OpenID_AX_FetchResponse();
$obj = $ax->fromSuccessResponse($response);

if($sreg)
{
   //sreg is supported, start creating the sreg data array.
}
elseif($obj)
{
   // attribute exchange supported. fetch details here
}
```

this will help you diagnose which data is coming, SREG or Atribute Exchange

Comment: How is $response generated?  The walkthrough I have simply creates an Auth_OpenID_Consumer object, sets the URL and redirects.  

The only time I see a response is in the return -- but I would assume sreg or ax needs to be determined prior to authorization. (?)

Thanks!

Comment: @jmccartie: I have edited my answer now, it includes where that $response came from.
For detailed explanation you can have a look at the files (the code in php files only) in the "examples/consumer/" directory of openid library.

Comment: But to get that AX in response we will probably need to request it first, like we request SREG? Or how this works?